# Display maximum value produced by loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have coded a loop (see below) that produces the follwoign values of sr: 10, 0, 7, 5, 3, and 7. I now want to modify the code so that it selects the largest value of sr - in this case 10. I have searched the intrernet, but have not had much luck. Please can you help?

Thanks,

Ollie

Code:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim sr As Long

For i = 2 To 7

x = i - 2

If Cells(4, i).Value <> 0 Then

sr = Range(Cells(3, i), Range("B3").Offset(0, x).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Else

sr = 0

'Debug.Print (sr)' - produces values: 10, 0, 7, 5, 3, and 7 

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim Old As Long
    Old = -99999
    For i = 2 To 7
        x = i - 2
        If Cells(4, i).Value <> 0 Then
            sr = Range(Cells(3, i), Range("B3").Offset(0, x).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Else
            sr = 0
        'Debug.Print (sr)' - produces values: 10, 0, 7, 5, 3, and 7
        End If
        If sr > Old Then
            Old = sr
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox Old
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary - a very elegant solution that doe steh trick!